# Python 3 - Need to make a program that will R/W a text file and show the amount of Char in new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a program, that will ask user for what .txt file they want to rewrite to a new file and what should the new files name be + the new file has to be in all uppercase. Also after doing that the program has to show the amount of symbols(characters) in the new file.

f1 ask the name of the file they want to re-write.

f2 ask what the new name should be.

```
#xxxxxxxxxxxx
f1 = input("xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxx: ):")
f2 = input("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxx: ):")

#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
FirstFail = open(f1, 'r')
NewOnes = FirstFail.readlines()

#xxxxxxxxx
Indeed = open(f2, 'w')
Indeed.write((str(NewOnes)).upper())


#xxxxxxxxxxxx
FirstFail.close()
```

Indeed.close()

```
#xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Sym = open(str(Indeed, 'r'))
print(str.count(start=0, end=len(Sym)))
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Sym = open(str(Indeed, 'r'))
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, _io.TextIOWrapper found
```

Now I know that Nfail is in the wrong format and I need to somehow change it but have no Idea how.

Comment: `open(str(Nfail, 'r'))` => `open(f2,'r')` `Nfail` is the _handle_, not the filename

Comment: I get the error that: TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()

Comment: that's the next error: `str.count(start=0, end=len(Sym))` makes no sense. What do you want to do.

Comment: oh wow I overlooked that, but I'm trying to print out the number of characters in the new f2 file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 2 last lines makes no sense:

```
Sym = open(str(Nfail, 'r'))
```

passes a `tuple(file handle,'r')` to `open`.

```
print(str.count(start=0, end=len(Sym)))
```

tries to call method `count` without object, and passing `len(Sym)` which can't work since `Sym` is a *file handle*

I'd rewrite that like this:

```
with open(f2, 'r') as Sym:
    print(len(Sym.read()))
```

also no need to read the file to get the size, just do:

```
print(os.path.getsize(f2))
```

(you may have a slight difference on windows because of `\r\n` => `\n` conversion but that's the fastest way to get a file size: the file isn't even read)

Comment: with open(f2, 'r') as Sym:
    print(len(Sym.read()))       This indeed worked, the other part #print(os.path.getsize(f2)) didn't work for me tho - got a os i not defined error. Thank you for your answear.